# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-gradle-plugin

> .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.20/e58b4816ac517e9cc5df1db051120c63d4cde669/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

project-level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.6.2'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

app-level `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.curious.bluetoothdevicesscanandconnect'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.curious.bluetoothdevicesscanandconnect"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }


    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.50'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.50'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0'
}
```

`gradle.wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside your project-level `build.gradle`, change:

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false`

to

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false`

---

2. Due to caching, gradle may be using an older dependency before you updated.

delete the `android/.gradle` directory

And you should be good to go.